# How do I unhide and remove disk mounts from Login Items?

Tags: login-items

Some time back I added some network disk mounts as Login Items for my MacBook Air (Mountain Lion).

When I'm away from my network, though, I'm constantly bothered by warning boxes saying "Can't connect" to those mounts.

I went to my Login Items screen, and rather than deleting them, I hid them. I failed to understand the +/- buttons and the checkbox.

Now I can't find a way to "unhide" those disk mounts from my Login Items, and successfully remove the automatic mounts.

Comment: Bad question: I was trying to eliminate network disk mounts when away from the home network. I think Time Machine was trying to access the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the following image, you can remove Login Items by selecting them (highlighting them) and clicking the "-" button. Hiding an item (by selecting the check box) in Login Items means that it is opened, but hidden.

[image]

Comment: Right, the thing is, what if an item is hidden and I want to remove it? How do I unhide it, so I can remove it?

Comment: You do understand that 'hiding' has nothing to do with an application's visibility in the preference pane, right? Do you see the rows of your disk images in the Login Items, or are they gone? I think there's been misconception between hiding (the check box, which means that the application runs on login, but its window is hidden) and actually not seeing it in Login Items' preference pane.

Comment: No I didn't realize that. The disk mounts are not visible in my Login Items screen. I thought that's because they were "hidden." So now I'm left with the puzzle of why I get the constant error messages when I'm away from my home network.

Comment: Maybe it's Time Machine trying to open that network disk.

Comment: that's a good thought @Mojo do you back up your network disk with TM?

Comment: Yes, Time Machine was my reason for the mounts in "Login Items". So it would appear to make finder stop complaining about not being able to mount a network volume, I need to turn off Time Machine when I'm away from my home network.